# Accessing Unity Layer's Names

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, yaml

Just wondering where the actual name for a given layer in Unity is stored. Upon checking the YAML file for the scene in question, the only hint I could find at layers were GameObjects having an 'm_Layer' value assigned to them by a number form 0-31 instead of a string with the Layer's actual name. So, setting a GameObject's layer inside or outside the editor is fairly straightforward, and a quick script to get the camera to mask certain layers is no problem, but I'd really like to know if I can edit the Layers themselves through yet another YAML or similar file.

Is there any way to access and/or modify a project's Layer name information outside of the editor, perhaps in the Library, Packages or ProjectSettings folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a file that contains that information, it's in *ProjectSettings/TagManager.asset* (under the "*layers:*" yaml block).  They are listed in numerical order.  This file contains both layers *and* tags but is only named "TagManager" for some (probably legacy) reason.

If you're looking for an API with that information, you can use the static methods on [`LayerMask`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) which has both a [`LayerToName`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.LayerToName.html) and [`NameToLayer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.NameToLayer.html) method.

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for a quick answer on how to get the list of Layers:

```
string[] layers = Enumerable.Range(0, 31).Select(index => LayerMask.LayerToName(index)).Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: That's pretty neat!